# Create row from Count Number

Tags: powershell

Hy,

im a powershell beginner...so im about to read Office 365 licenses like this:

```
$licensetype = Get-MsolAccountSku | Where {$_.ConsumedUnits -ge 1}
```

| AccountSkuId | Free |
| --- | --- |
| reseller-account:SPB | 1 |
| reseller-account:EXCHANGESTANDARD | 2 |
| reseller-account:O365_BUSINESS_ESSENTIALS | 4 |

now i need a splitted result for free licenses like this:

| License | Free |
| --- | --- |
| SPB | 1 |
| EXCHANGESTANDARD | 1 |
| EXCHANGESTANDARD | 1 |
| EXCHANGESTANDARD | 1 |
| O365_BUSINESS_ESSENTIALS | 1 |
| O365_BUSINESS_ESSENTIALS | 1 |
| O365_BUSINESS_ESSENTIALS | 1 |
| O365_BUSINESS_ESSENTIALS | 1 |

i tried some foreach params, but without luck...any ideas?

Comment: From where/how are you reading the existing license information?

Comment: Get-MsolAccountSku | Where {$_.ConsumedUnits -ge 1} and then i use math to get the free units back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution i found:

```
$licensefree =  Get-MsolAccountSku | Where {($_.ConsumedUnits -ge 1) -and ($_.AccountSkuId -ne "reseller-account:FLOW_FREE") -and (($_.ActiveUnits - $_.ConsumedUnits) -ne 0)}  | Select-Object AccountSkuId,@{Name='Free';Expression={$_.ActiveUnits - $_.ConsumedUnits}}

$EndObject = @()
foreach ($Sku in $licensefree) {
$i = 1
while ($i -le [int]$Sku.Free) {
$EndObject += $Sku.AccountSkuId 
$i++
}
}
$EndObject
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming the get-msolaccountssku returns you objects with the properties as declared in the first table you can do:

```
#Get Lincense Info
$licensetype = Get-MsolAccountSku | Where {$_.ConsumedUnits -ge 1}

$result = @(
    foreach ($lt in $licensetype){
        $attrsHt = [ordered]@{
            AccountSkuId = $lt.AccountSkuId
            ActiveUnits = $lt.ActiveUnits
            WarningUnits = $lt.WarningUnits
            ConsumedUnits = $lt.ConsumedUnits
            Free = ([int]($lt.ActiveUnits) - [int]($lt.ConsumedUnits))
        }
        New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $attrsHt
    }
)
```

The variable $result contains the information. Or you could also achieve the same by using calculated property in conjunction with select-object:

```
$licenseInfo =  Get-MsolAccountSku | Where {$_.ConsumedUnits -ge 1} | Select-Object AccountSkuId,ActiveUnits,WarningUnits,ConsumedUnits,@{Name='Free';Expression={$_.ActiveUnits - $_.ConsumedUnits}}
```

Comment: `$licensefree =  Get-MsolAccountSku | Where {($_.ConsumedUnits -ge 1) -and ($_.AccountSkuId -ne "reseller-account:FLOW_FREE") -and (($_.ActiveUnits - $_.ConsumedUnits) -ne 0)}  | Select-Object AccountSkuId,@{Name='Free';Expression={$_.ActiveUnits - $_.ConsumedUnits}}` Now i get only free licenses, but how can i "explode" them? the previous code doesnt seem to work

Comment: what do you mean with "explode"? sorry if it does not work as expected, can't test as I am not using the *-msol* cmdlets

Comment: i need the results not as count, but seperated...f.e.:
EXCHANGEONLINE: 3
to
EXCHANGEONLINE
EXCHANGEONLINE
EXCHANGEONLINE

Answer (score 0):

```
$licensefree =  Get-MsolAccountSku | Where {($_.ConsumedUnits -ge 1) -and 
($_.AccountSkuId -ne "reseller-account:FLOW_FREE") -and (($_.ActiveUnits - 
$_.ConsumedUnits) -ne 0)}  | Select-Object 
AccountSkuId,@{Name='Free';Expression={$_.ActiveUnits - $_.ConsumedUnits}}


$explodedList = foreach($License in $licensefree) {
for($i = 0; $i -lt $licensefree.Free; $i++){
    # Create a copy of the object
    [pscustomobject]@{
        License = $licensefree.License
        Free = ''
    }
}
}
$explodedList
```

Output ERROR:

```
"0" konnte nicht mit "1 2 4" verglichen werden. Fehler: "Der Wert "System.Object[]" vom Typ "System.Object[]" kann nicht in den Typ "System.Int32" konvertiert werden."
In Zeile:2 Zeichen:17
+     for($i = 0; $i -lt $licensefree.Free; $i++){
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComparisonFailure
```

Comment: the issue here is that $licensefree is the array containing all information and not a single element. you should use $License.free then it should work. But I don't get why you do 2 loops (foreach/for). think the for loop is not necessary here.

Comment: if i run $licensefree, i get only License Name and Free Units...and nothing else